# Jmeter script recorder and recording for multiple users/threads

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I created in Jmeter a Test Plan that looks like that:

[image]

the idea is to keep track of all the APIs the browser access between two pages. So, I open the localhost:63948/Home/LoginEmailSenha and I go until the other page I want. Under the Recording Controller label I get the list of the APIs.

But what can I do so that it feels like there isn't only one person accessing but actually 200? I tried to change the Number of Threads(users) at the Thread Group but nothing seems to change as I want to get the API errors that occured because there are too many people.

Comment: you are confusing a few concepts here: recorder is just a proxy, it would record any HTTP traffic going through it, and has nothing to do with users / browser tabs etc. Once you done recording, you should click Stop, and forget about it (btw HTTPS Domains parameter is supposed to contain domains accessed using HTTPs, not some HTTP URL). Your actual question refers to execution of the script it seems, but it's very unclear. For example: what's your script looks like? what was the Number of Threads? what did you actually see in (for example) results tree?etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) is used to create a test scenario "skeleton", it basically stands between browser and application under test, captures requests and generates relevant [HTTP Request samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request).

If you need to mimic 200 users you need to **replay** the recorded scenario with increased number of threads.

References:

- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
- [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html)
- [Building an Advanced Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-adv-web-test-plan.html)

---

If your target is to simulate the load during recording time you can take a look at [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension), it has [FollowMe Mode](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732859-Chrome-Extension-FollowMe) when any your online activity is replicated with a given number of virtual users.